# Regex for matching state and postal code

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that matches the following strings in a big block of text:

```
California 94558
California 94558-0000
North Dakota  88888
ND  88888-8888
```

Double and single spaces are necessary between state and zip.

So far I have this:

```js
/([a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+))\s+(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)/g
```

But I cannot get it to work with single word states.  I would also like to add Canada postal codes, but I think I won't confuse things here.

Comment: Instead of trying to verify both simultaneously, split on the last space and validate the zip separately from the state. If you insist on doing both, see that `(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)` may appear *zero* or one time. Hint: you don't handle the "zero" case

Comment: ([a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)?)\s+(\d{5}(-\d{4})?), group 1 match state, and group 3 match postal code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually very close. Your regex only needs specifying that the space-2nd word combo is *optional*. I only added a single `?` to make it work:

```
([a-zA-Z]+(\s+[a-zA-Z]+)?)\s+(\d{5}([\-]\d{4})?)
                        ^ there
```

A slightly neater way is to suppress capturing all matched groups, and just pick up the two most useful ones:

```
([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)?)\s+(\d{5}(?:[\-]\d{4})?)
```

Now Group 1 will always contain the state – one or two words – and Group 2 will always hold the zip code.

See also the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/9I8DOz/1).

Answer (score 0):

If your always expecting `state state zip` or `state zip`

you can break this down to this pattern `^\w+\s+(\w|\d|\s)+-?\d+` with `mg` flag for multi-line and global regex match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex!

```
[a-zA-Z]+\s?[a-zA-Z]+\s+\d{5}(-\d{4})?
```

Below is the output of above regex in [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

[image: regex output]